# Unable to install beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, installation, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 2.7.5 on windows , i tried installing BeautifulSoup , after running

```
setup.py install
```

i got this screen : - 
[image]

but on importing , displays that there is no module with that name .
Please help guys .

Comment: Edit your question showing us the output of: `python -c "import sys; from pprint import pprint; pprint(sys.path); print(sys.executable)"`. Also, show us how you're calling python (including pasting some code which calls this import), and the full error message. All of this will help in determining how you're importing it, as well as what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the current working directory to another directory. Weird things happen when after you installing the Python Library and stay in the library folder.